# How to get STRING query string value using php

Tags: php

Suppose if I have string like this:

```
rajeshpatel&rid=10&sid=20&mid=30
```

Then how can I get value of `"rid"` using php.

any help?

Comment: two upvote on this question?interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`parse_str`](https://secure.php.net/parse_str) as

```
$str = 'rajeshpatel&rid=10&sid=20&mid=30';
parse_str($str,$result);
print_r($result);
echo $result['rid'];//10
```

Or you can use it in another way as

```
parse_str($str);
echo $rid;//10
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/392320)

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't call me sir. And that's why SO is created for